# Tag synonym request: fraction and fractions

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

[fractions](/questions/tagged/fractions) and [fraction](/questions/tagged/fraction) both exist and have no distinguishable difference. [fraction](/questions/tagged/fraction) has a good tag summary, but I think the better name is [fractions](/questions/tagged/fractions).

Comment: I've copied the tag Wiki data from fraction to fractions and there are no longer any questions tagged fraction.  The only thing left is to make the names formally synonymous (but the singular tag will vanish soon because there are no questions tagged by it).

Answer (score 1):

I think that fractions should be used, as there is more then one. However I think That they should be synonyms in some way regardless.